# In Tiger Woods 12 which skills should be maxed if NOT using the PS3 move controller?

Tags: ps3, tiger-woods-pga-tour-12

SO I gave up on the move controller for PS3 in TW12.  Its fun, and it makes putting a lot less error prone (IMHO), but my drives and approaches are more accurate and more powerful without the move so I'm switching back.....

question : Which skills are good to max out if you're not using the move? In particular, I really want to make putting more forgiving, but I think tempo and feel and so forth are all geared towards the Move.  In general, which skills should I just take all points away from if I'm not using Move?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so as a first time user of Tiger Woods I think I was a little off base here.
I'd still like an answer to this when using the 3-click method, but for using the analog sticks instead of move you can follow the same basic advice. 
 Which is... everything is somewhat important except putting "Tempo", which is the duration that the yellow bar stays on the screen when putting.  This isn't worth a lot of investment unless you have XP to burn. 
 Personally, I don't use Choke (under Control) much so I wont concentrate on that for any control style. 
Other than that the only other difference between analog sticks and move, is that boost is less effective with analog, so don't bother maxing that out. I could get in the 130% range w/ Move and lots of boost....like 105% with analog.

So, if there any 3-click TW12 users out there, feel free to englighten!

Good resource/tutorial for the various XP skills : 
http://insideblog.easports.com/archive/2011/03/28/tiger-woods-pga-tour-12-the-masters-tips-amp-tricks-hub.aspx